# Is there an iOS SMS Texting app that allows parent to get a record of all texting messages?

Tags: software-recommendation, ios, sms

My son (pre-teen) received an iPod Touch for Christmas.  He has a friend that does not have an iOS device.  But his friend can text.  I am still at the stage and my son is still of the age that I would like to have a way to know when he is texting and what he is texting.  Is there an app for that?

[It could be something that allows me to setup an account and login to a website to see activity.]

Comment: I suppose your son was using iMessage to send the text? Since iPod Touch doesn't support cellular SMS. As far as I know there is no monitoring app for iMessage, but it could be done if the device is jail broken. Then he may switch to Skype or other text services, and you'll have to adapt as well.

Comment: can't be iMessage if the friend doesn't have an iOS device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this app.

[SMS Touch](http://www.smstouch.info/SMS_touch/SMS_touch.html) that allows you to setup email address to send copy of SMS content.  SMS are purchased in app.

Net Nanny are also bringing out an iOS app to monitor and restrict iOS devices in young persons hands. details  [here](http://www.netnanny.com/ios)

> NET NANNY FOR IOS includes Filtering (18 categories), Age-based Profiles, Safe Search, Profanity Masking, and supports Wi-Fi/3G/4G.
>
> NET NANNY SUITE FOR IOS includes all the features of Net Nanny for iOS plus Remote Administration, Reports, Custom Categories, Whitelist/Blacklist. Future releases within the next few months will include Time Controls, Custom Alerts, Reports, and device management tools such as Device Locate and Forced Ring. All new features will be auto-updated for existing users.

Comment: Thank you for the down vote. you may have missed  the posters original note that his friend does not have an iOS device therefore iMessages is out of the equation in this instance

Comment: You know, I actually completely glossed over that detail. I am sooooo sorry! Unfortunately I can't change the vote without you changing the post. Maybe add a link to Net Nanny / some details about it? I'll change it ASAP after that.